# What happens to the ATP after it stores energy?

Tags: cellular-respiration

The title says it all. After the procceses of cellular respiration happen,  the energy is used in different activities that use it, but which are them, more specifically?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to demonstrate you have done your own research before asking a question.Yours is a basic question that is covered in many biochemistry and biology texts, such as [Berg et al. on-line](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/?term=ATP). If you have any specific questions after doing that, then it is OK to post them here, explaining what you do not understand. But check previous questions first.

Comment: this is one of those questions that could be answered by a quick visit to wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate

Answer (score -1):

Well first of all, how is ATP used in metabolic processes? The build up of molecules require energy. And the best molecule in biological livijg systems is ATP.

One of the processes that require ATP is the very process that makes it: **glycolysis**. The body will reconfigure the shape of glycolysis, transforming it into a precursor of pyruvate. This first phase (a.k.a *investment phase* requires two ATPs, dephosphorylating it into two ADPs. And to recap the payoff phase, once the main molecule is split, the molecule will breakdown into pyruvate through another set of various steps. At the same time, two ADPs will be phosphorylated into two ATPS. This phosphorylation occurs for each of the two pyruvates.

So the one of the main purposes for ATP is for the build up of molecules. The energy of ATP is released when it is convenient for into ADP + P, and is transferred to the new, bigger molecule.

Another process that ATP is involved in is activation. In neuron cells, the sodium potassium pump is constantly trying to set a concentration gradient between sodium in the cytoplasm and potassium in the extracellular fluid. And because it is working non-stop, it needs ATP to continue working. However, in the scenario where an individual is deprived of oxygen through an extended period of time, brain damage may occur due to the the absence of ATP production. The sodium potassium gradient will never be restored, and the neuron will be unusable.